# MS SQL Server: Populating empty table column with lag of same column + calculations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to fill in the NULL values in Column C of my example:

```
ID Date     ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
A  1/1/2018 0       0       NULL
A  2/1/2018 1       2       NULL
A  3/1/2018 1       2       NULL
```

with the lagged values of ColumnC so that:

```
(ColumnB + Lag(ColumnC,1,0) over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) - ColumnA) AS ColumnC

ID Date     ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
A  1/1/2018 0       0       0
A  2/1/2018 1       2       1
A  3/1/2018 1       2       2
```

Unfortunately the lag() function is failing me here (I'm using SQL Server)

Thanks!

*Edit: Added ID and date columns to show desired PARTITION and ORDER*

Comment: Is the `lag()` function throwing an error?

Comment: The lag function returns a value of 0 in the first row as expected. _However_, all subsequent rows remain NULL

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  To talk about the previous row, you need  a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: added two add'l columns to show desired partition and order, sorry for any confusion

Comment: What is this for?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need recursive query to achieve the required result.
Please note that:

```
ColumnC         = ColumnB + Lag(ColumnC,1,0) - ColumnA
--calculated                -- LAG refer to the same column
```

Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0)  
            -- quite dangerous, you need specific column
  FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT rn, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC=ColumnB-ColumnA
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.rn, t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnB-t2.ColumnA+t.ColumnC
  FROM cte2 t
  JOIN cte t2
    ON t.rn = t2.rn-1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a30acbb000657894cf9cb37d022fe0f7)**

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE.  But what you really want is a cumulative sum:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, sum(ColumnB - ColumnA) over (partition by id order by date) as new_columnC
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set columnC = new_columnC;
```

I can let you work out the math that shows that this is what you intend.

Note the `?`.  This is the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Thanks! With a little modification this did the trick!

`with toupdate as (
      select t.*, sum(ColumnB - ColumnA) over (partition by id order by date) as new_ColumnC
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set ColumnC = new_ColumnC;`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
SELECT 
    ID
,   [Date]
,   ColumnA 
,   ColumnB
,   ColumnB + ISNULL(ColumnC,0) - ColumnA AS ColumnC
FROM (
SELECT 
    ID
,   [Date]
,   ColumnA 
,   ColumnB
,   LAG(ColumnB) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date]) AS ColumnC
FROM yourTable
WHERE 
    ColumnC IS NULL
) D
```

Since the first row will be always NULL in LAG(), we could use ISNULL() function to replace it with 0. note that I've specified `ColumnC IS NULL` to ensure that the results will be applied only on NULLs on ColumnC.